# Multisite with subdirectories, and a WordPress installation in a custom folder

Tags: customization, multisite

My WP core code is located in a subfolder, next to the `index.php` and `wp-config.php` files. I tried to enable the multisite functionalities with `subdirectories` mode.
But I cannot access to the wp-admin's.

To be clear:

- the main website is accessible through: https://www.example.com
- the main wp-admin: https://www.example.com/core-wp/wp-admin/
- "site1" website: https://www.example.com/site1
- "site1" wp-admin: ??

It seems WP doesn't allow us to mix custom core folder and multisite subdirectories.
Or maybe I missed a configuration or a constant:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Whereas I can see these two options for the main website:

- `siteurl`: https://www.example.com/core-wp
- `home`: https://www.example.com

Did you experienced this kind of installation and did you find a way to access to subdirectories site wp-admin's ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you try to access the main admin through the "/core-wp" subfolder? You should typically access the main admin via https://www.example.com//wp-admin/. What kind of server are you using? Site one wp-admin should be https://www.example.com/site1/wp-admin

Comment: @Badan : the configuration adds security points by changing the core WP folder. It's frequent to see that kind of configuration. I wanted to know if someone has seen this kind of configuration